# Use of "wie" as a subordinating conjunction

Tags: word-choice, conjunction

In the following sentence:

> Ich muss mir einen Plan ausdenken, wie ich in kurzer Zeit viel Geld verdienen kann.

Does "wie" here mean "dass", "sodass" or "damit"? Or something else?

Comment: What does your dictionary propose as translations for "wie"? Have you played with parts of the sentence in an online translator? I'm probably missing something, but this seems so obvious to me that I probably don't really get the heart of the question.

Comment: This is so straightforward that you wouldn't even need a dictionary. Just a hint: ***Wie** kann ich Geld verdienen?* = ***___** can I earn money?*

Comment: I know "wie" means "how", but how would the sentence be translated then? //I need to come up with a plan, how I can earn a lot of money in less time// doesn't sound right to my ears

Comment: I think it should be something like: //I need to come up with a plan, so that I can make a lot of money in less time//.

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI, but that is the correct translation (*..., how I can earn a lot of money*). It's about *how to do it* and not about *so that you can do it*.

Comment: You're right that "... ,, how I can earn a lot of money in less time," is not correct English; at the least it's awkward and non-idiomatic phrasing. It's a word for word translation which is rarely satisfactory. This is something you need to get used to when translating; you need to translate the *meaning*, not just the words. The best, or even the correct, phrasing of the same meaning in different languages can be quite different.

Comment: It would have been possible to answer this question instead of closing it.  I find it understandable that the OP thought that “wie” must be a conjunction and did not recognise it as a question word (or whatever those are called in Latin ;) ).